# How to position divs side by side?

Tags: css

I have four div class and a button which together make up an individual advert on a site.

```
.awpcp-listing-primary-image-thumbnail
.a
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-content
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner
```

I would like to group each set together (1 advert)  to display two side by side in mobile and 4 side by side in desktop. How do I do this with css?

Html:

```
<div class="awpcp-listings awpcp-clearboth">
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt displayaditemseven
    $isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp-
    listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small":
    [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
      <a class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-listing-link"
         href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-
    2/awpcp-show-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-
    service/london/uk/westminster/business-advert/"><img
          class="awpcp-listing-primary-image-thumbnail"
          alt="Nico&#039;s Cleaning Service"
          src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-
    content/uploads/awpcp/thumbs
    /flyermaker_15032019_134523-ac957ffd-primary.png"
          width="80"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
      <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a
          href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-
    2/awpcp-show-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-*
    service/london/uk/westminster/business-
    advert/">Nico&#039;s Cleaning Service</a></h4>
      <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">We are
        professional domestic cleaners in London. £12.00 per
        hour, all equipment and materials need to be provided,
        minimum booking&hellip;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
      03/21/2019<br/>
      London<br/>
      Price: £ 12.00
    </div>
```

Comment: show your html please

Comment: See above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS flex and flex-flow property.

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-flow/